# Checking for duplicate with encrypted values

Tags: php, programming-practices, mysql

I was hoping to get some advice on a particular task I'm trying to implement.

I have a table that stores secure data and returns an ID as a representation of that data. No problems there. So, for example, if a social security number is stored, the code generates a representational ID and stores the social security number in an encrypted fashion in the table. The encryption is done using envelope encryption.

Here's my issue. Every time a new value comes in, I don't want to create a new ID if the data already exists. I need to check to see if the value already exists and, if so, return the existing ID. The problem I have is that the encrypted value is different each time and I certainly can't decrypt every value in the database to check for a duplicate. I could create a one way hash and store that as well but, if I do, I would need to salt it for security purposes and the hash will be different every time.

So I'm hoping to get advice/recommendations on how to achieve this? How to check for duplicates when the value is stored in an encrypted fashion.

Thank you!

Comment: The usual method as you say is to use a one-way hash. The same value should produce the same hash - which you simply compare (indexing the hashes if necessary). I can't see why you need to use a function that produces a different hash each time for the same value - properly hashed values are secure.

Comment: @Steve hashes are not reversible (are not simetric). I guess the value is encrypted because they want to be able to keep It hidden and recoverbale. As you commented, the solution would take just a new column to store the hash and compare hashes during the validation. Which algo. depends on the needs. I encourage you to write an answer, I think your solution is both simple and functional.

Comment: @Steve, there are only a billion possible social security numbers, so a rainbow table can be created with relatively modest resources.  If you have a different random salt per row, the effort to create a rainbow table multiplies by the number of rows.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt, I see your point. Maybe you'll have to accept inserting duplicates as the price of security, and occasionally run a de-duplication job which does decrypt all values and identifies any duplicates that have accumulated.

Answer (score 1):

Since a single hash of a value can be vulnerable to brute force, rainbow tables, or even a simple Google search for the hashed value and using a unique salt per row does not allow you to perform keyed lookups you should consider if a keyed hash (HMAC) would meet your needs.

With an HMAC you need to generate a cryptographically random key that is not stored alongside the data, but can be accessed by the application.

You then use the [hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) function to calculate the HMAC of a given identifier value (using the key generated from above). That is a unique value that you can then store alongside the data and use to determine if you have already inserted a row with that value before.

You should ensure that you select a strong hashing function (such as SHA256) to ensure that the HMAC is as strong as possible.

Using an HMAC will mitigate the risk of information disclosure via brute force/rainbow tables as long as your secret key is sufficiently random and  remains secret. You should protect that key just as you are protecting your encryption keys.